# Cannot resolbe symbol "from"

Tags: java, android

Не могу разобраться в чем ошибка, AS подсвечивает ошибку в слове "from" - "cannot resolve symbol "from"", подскажите пожалуйста как её исправить ?

Код:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

class PersonAdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapterClass.ViewHolder> {

    List<PersonModelClass> person;
    Context context;
    DataBaseHelperClass dataBaseHelperClass;

    public PersonAdapterClass(List<PersonModelClass> person, Context context) {
        this.person = person;
        this.context = context;
        dataBaseHelperClass = new DataBaseHelperClass(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = new LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
```

[image: Скрин с ошибкой]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед LayoutInflater уберите new.

Comment: Большое спасибо !! Очень невнимательно посмотрел